# Weird color distortion when using an effect on top of an image in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

In Adobe InDesign, I have placed a pink image that I brought in from Photoshop. The below screenshot is how the pink looks like in Mac Preview (I'm on Mountain Lion).

[image]

I wanted to add some lines to that background, so I whipped something up in Illustrator. The result was as I expected:

[image]

But then I decided to turn down the opacity of the stripes. All of a sudden, the exported PDF has a much darker and subdued pink background:

[image]

I then removed the transparency effect, and the bright pink came right back. I later found that if I applied any effect to an element on top of my pink background, the pink changes from "bright pink" to "dark pink". Why is this the case? I don't know if this is related, but in InDesign, the pink is dark as well. When I export it as a PDF, however, the bright pink comes back (and looks the same as in the PSD file).

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out (naturally, after I submitted the question)! The problem was that I had my Transparency Blend Space set to "Document CMYK" instead of "Document RGB". Now the bright pink is showing up regardless of what I throw on top of it, and the bright pink shows up within InDesign as well.

You can change your Transparency Blend Space by going to the `Edit > Transparency Blend Space` submenu.

I hope this helps whoever else is having the same problem!

Comment: :))
It happened to me too, quite a few times
(figuring it out after posting the question)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry about whether you are in CMYK or RGB, just right-click on the gradient/overlayed object and select `Effects > Transparency`. Set the blend mode as `Multiply`.

This will appear to add the colors together instead of subtracting them, which is what results in the dirty gray look (lack of color) you are trying to avoid.

Comment: +1 for the very interesting workaround! I'm sure this tip will come in handy sometime. Thanks!